# How change yeoman generator-webapp settings to make uploadble files

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

I begin to use yeoman to make web pages.  I finished almost. And I typed 'grunt' not 'grunt serve' to make up-loadable files.

terminal said errors below.But Cords work.

what should I fix.

```
app/scripts/main.js
```

2:3   error  Strings must use singlequote                            quotes

2:3   error  Expected indentation of 4 space characters but found 2  indent

5:7   error  "slideqty" is defined but never used                no-unused-vars

50:5   error  "map" is defined but never used                         no-unused-vars
  52:1   error  Expected indentation of 2 space characters but found 0  indent
  55:17  error  "google" is not defined                                 no-undef
  58:13  error  "google" is not defined                                 no-undef
  62:1   error  "google" is not defined                                 no-undef
  62:1   error  Expected indentation of 2 space characters but found 0  indent

✖ 22 problems (22 errors, 0 warnings)

Warning: Task "eslint:target" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.

Comment: no question mark found

Comment: Hi bro, did u get ans for this? Need help for the same.